# Flask - Display datafram as table

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a route in my flask app which generates a list of dicts. Im trying to display that list as a table. However when I navigate to my route, the page is blank and Im not sure why

Code:

app.py

```
@app.route('/<car_name>')
def generate_display_data(card_name):
    # code...
    df= pd.DataFrame(table)
    return render_template('car_info.html', tables=[df.to_html], header="true")
```

the list table looks like this:

```
[
 {'id': 6, 'image': 'de.png', 'name': '...', 'Type': '...' },
 {'id': 96, 'image': 'c4.png', 'name': '...', 'Type': '...' },
 {'id': 82, 'image': '4.png', 'name': '...', 'Type': '...' },
 {'id': 98, 'image': '37.png', 'name': '...', 'Type': '...' }
]
```

car_info.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% for table in tables %}
            {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

When I run my app. I can see that the list `table` is being generated correctly but I see a blank html page. What am I missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the function reference (`df.to_html`) to `tables` instead of the result of calling the function.

Instead of this

```
return render_template('car_info.html', tables=[df.to_html], header="true")
```

do this

```
return render_template("car_info.html", tables=[df.to_html()], header="true")
```